# How to search a RDF object with Apache Jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

My program as the following reads an external RDF file.

```
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(fileName);
    model.read(in, "RDF/XML");

    NodeIterator iter = model.listObjects();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(" " + iter.next().toString());
    }
```

What I want to implement further is...

1. return whether there is a RDF object whose `rdf:resource` is "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut" (In this case, return `true`)
2. Extract the value of `rdf:about` (In this case, return `../descriptor/14066-0`)

*Example RDF*

```xml
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="../descriptor/14066-0">
    <skos:closeMatch rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut"/>
  </rdf:Description>
```

Which methods can I use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of the data.  Resources don't "have an `rdf:resource`" or a "value of `rdf:about`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't make sense as written. In the data you've provided, there is there is a single triple

```
<../descriptor/14066-0> skos:closeMatch <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut>
```

rdf:about is just an artifact of the RDF/XML serialization, and it indicates the URI of the resource, just like rdf:resource does in the property value.  Given that, what you're probably is asking by

> 1. return whether there is a RDF object whose rdf:resource is
>      "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut" (In this case, return true)
> 2. Extract the value of rdf:about (In this case, return
>      ../descriptor/14066-0)

is values of `?resource` such that:

```
?resource skos:closeMatch dbpedia:Coconut
```

That's easiest to do with a SPARQL query, but you can also do it programmatically.  Here's an example.  Note that subjects can also be blank nodes, in which case they won't have a URI.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.jena.riot.Lang;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;

public class CoconutExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String data = "" +
                "@prefix skos: <http://skos.com/> .\n" +
                "@prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .\n" +
                "@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24247503/1281433> .\n" +
                "\n" +
                ":lovelyBunch skos:closeMatch dbpedia:Coconut .\n" +
                ":uglyBunch skos:closeMatch dbpedia:Banana .\n" +
                "_:blankBunch skos:closeMatch dbpedia:Coconut .\n";

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        try ( ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream( data.getBytes() ) ) {
            model.read( in, null, "TTL" );
        }

        // Show the model
        System.out.println( "=== Model ===" );
        RDFDataMgr.write( System.out, model, Lang.RDFXML );

        // Ask for triples programmatically
        Property closeMatch = model.createProperty( "http://skos.com/closeMatch" );
        Resource coconut = model.createResource( "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut" );
        System.out.println( "\n=== Subjects ===" );
        for ( StmtIterator s = model.listStatements( null, closeMatch, coconut ); s.hasNext() ; ) {
            System.out.println( "* " + s.next().getSubject() );
        }

        // Ask with a SPARQL query
        String query = "select ?x { ?x <http://skos.com/closeMatch> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut> }";
        System.out.println( "\n=== SPARQL results ===" );
        ResultSetFormatter.out( QueryExecutionFactory.create( query, model ).execSelect() );
    }
}
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:skos="http://skos.com/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24247503/1281433"
    xmlns:dbpedia="http://dbpedia.org/resource/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24247503/1281433lovelyBunch">
    <skos:closeMatch rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24247503/1281433uglyBunch">
    <skos:closeMatch rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Banana"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description>
    <skos:closeMatch rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Coconut"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```
* 62a8a69f5ee83a9106ee42859f6c60fc
* http://stackoverflow.com/q/24247503/1281433lovelyBunch
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| x                                                        |
============================================================
| _:b0                                                     |
| <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24247503/1281433lovelyBunch> |
------------------------------------------------------------
```